# Windows-8 how do I write a script to change the resolution?

Tags: windows-8, script, powershell, resolution

I have a yoga 2 pro that comes with a high resolution display (2k I believe). This sometimes causes issues with programs not scaling properly which for the most part I can ignore.

However I also remote desktop in to my work computer, which only has a 1080p display. This makes working really difficult since the remote session is done at 3200x1800. So I end up changing the resolution every time by right clicking the desktop>change resolution>select resolution>hit accept>accept popup.

Is there a script that I could write to automate this for me? So I can easily switch back and forth between resolutions. Bonus points if there is a way to alter the font scaling as well!!!

I did some searching and found some powerscript commands but I could not get them to work...

Edit:
Found this answer here that says powershell cannot do it [How to do a Powershell (or other) script to change screen resolution?](https://superuser.com/questions/29450/how-to-do-a-powershell-or-other-script-to-change-screen-resolution?rq=1)

Guess I can find a utility online. Any recommendations?

Comment: mstsc itself has an option to set the resolution - have you tried this? It's on "Display" tab.

Comment: I was using the windows 8 remote desktop app. That does not let me do it.

Comment: @ScottRhee I was about to suggest the same, but you beat me to it.. Any decent RDP client (even those NOT made by Microsoft) has such an option build in. I use that daily to connect my 5K iMac to a Windows 7 box with a regular HD display. I have to force the RDP session to use the same resolution because I have some applications  on Windows that hate a change in resolution while they are running.

Answer (score 0):

The following Powershell script will set the resolution to a specified value (in my example, 1280 x 1024):
-- *Just noticed that this is the same script referenced in your linked article. It works, I've tested it on Win 8.1 Pro and Enterprise.*

```
    Function Set-ScreenResolution { 

<# 
    .Synopsis 
        Sets the Screen Resolution of the primary monitor 
    .Description 
        Uses Pinvoke and ChangeDisplaySettings Win32API to make the change 
    .Example 
        Set-ScreenResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768         
    #> 
param ( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
           Position = 0)] 
[int] 
$Width, 

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
           Position = 1)] 
[int] 
$Height 
) 

$pinvokeCode = @" 

using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace Resolution 
{ 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
    public struct DEVMODE1 
    { 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public string dmDeviceName; 
        public short dmSpecVersion; 
        public short dmDriverVersion; 
        public short dmSize; 
        public short dmDriverExtra; 
        public int dmFields; 

        public short dmOrientation; 
        public short dmPaperSize; 
        public short dmPaperLength; 
        public short dmPaperWidth; 

        public short dmScale; 
        public short dmCopies; 
        public short dmDefaultSource; 
        public short dmPrintQuality; 
        public short dmColor; 
        public short dmDuplex; 
        public short dmYResolution; 
        public short dmTTOption; 
        public short dmCollate; 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public string dmFormName; 
        public short dmLogPixels; 
        public short dmBitsPerPel; 
        public int dmPelsWidth; 
        public int dmPelsHeight; 

        public int dmDisplayFlags; 
        public int dmDisplayFrequency; 

        public int dmICMMethod; 
        public int dmICMIntent; 
        public int dmMediaType; 
        public int dmDitherType; 
        public int dmReserved1; 
        public int dmReserved2; 

        public int dmPanningWidth; 
        public int dmPanningHeight; 
    }; 



    class User_32 
    { 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE1 devMode); 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE1 devMode, int flags); 

        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1; 
        public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01; 
        public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1; 
    } 



    public class PrmaryScreenResolution 
    { 
        static public string ChangeResolution(int width, int height) 
        { 

            DEVMODE1 dm = GetDevMode1(); 

            if (0 != User_32.EnumDisplaySettings(null, User_32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm)) 
            { 

                dm.dmPelsWidth = width; 
                dm.dmPelsHeight = height; 

                int iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_TEST); 

                if (iRet == User_32.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED) 
                { 
                    return "Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience."; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY); 
                    switch (iRet) 
                    { 
                        case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
                            { 
                                return "Success"; 
                            } 
                        case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: 
                            { 
                                return "You Need To Reboot For The Change To Happen.\n If You Feel Any Problem After Rebooting Your Machine\nThen Try To Change Resolution In Safe Mode."; 
                            } 
                        default: 
                            { 
                                return "Failed To Change The Resolution"; 
                            } 
                    } 

                } 


            } 
            else 
            { 
                return "Failed To Change The Resolution."; 
            } 
        } 

        private static DEVMODE1 GetDevMode1() 
        { 
            DEVMODE1 dm = new DEVMODE1(); 
            dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm); 
            return dm; 
        } 
    } 
} 

"@ 

Add-Type $pinvokeCode -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
[Resolution.PrmaryScreenResolution]::ChangeResolution($width,$height) 
} 

Set-ScreenResolution 1280 1024
```