# Any way to change the screen resolution automatically when I'm executing a program

Tags: windows-7, windows, resolution

I have a old game that works only with low screen resolutions, I'm tired of right-click > Screen Resolution and choose resolution

Is there a way to change the resolution automatically before start program?

Comment: some of the GPU card software would allow for a "preset" or a "profile" to be created which can be triggered with a hotkey or via the notification tray icon, or even with a shortcut. AMD catalyst (for example) will allow for running a program on the application of that preset.   That is one possibility, untested.  you could make a batch http://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line?rq=1 have an icon that does both, even get any needed waits in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compatibility mode.

1. Find the executable `.exe` file the application uses to start. Usually you can find it by right-clicking on a shortcut/link that launches the program (even in the start menu), clicking "Properites" and then "Open file location". Alternatively you can look at the path that is written in the same menu.
2. Once found the executable, right click on it, then "Properties" and choose the tab "Compatibility". There you'll be able to tick an option for the 640x480 resolution.

Comment: Compatibility tab does not include any option related with screen resolutions, only I find Windows version compatibility and other options

Comment: @CodigosTutoriales There should be a tick to enable 640x480 px resolution. At least on Windows 7, which is the OS of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a powershell script, that would change the screen resolution, then launch the executable of the old game. Then you'd just have to link that powershell script to a shortcut, placed maybe on your desktop.

Here are some links discussing how to change the screen resolution in powershell:

[How to do a Powershell (or other) script to change screen resolution?](https://superuser.com/q/29450/297225)
http://kindleit.blogspot.com/2012/09/changing-screen-resolution-with.html
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/07/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-change-my-desktop-monitor-resolution-via-windows-powershell.aspx