# Set zoom for built in display?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, automation, zoom

Is there a way to set the zoom for the internal display?  I know if I were to use powershell to input:
 `$Host.PrivateData.Zoom = 150` 
it would zoom just the powershell window to 150%.  I need "everything" to be 200%.

Answer (score 1):

Zoom is something that is part of Windows apps.

Screen resolution is what it sounds like you are after, meaning to expand everything on that screen.

See these discussions and sample code.

> Sets the resolution of the main monitor- Requires PowerShell V2
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2a631d72-206d-4036-a3f2-2e150f297515
>
> How to do a Powershell (or other) script to change screen resolution?
>
> [How to do a Powershell (or other) script to change screen resolution?](https://superuser.com/questions/29450/how-to-do-a-powershell-or-other-script-to-change-screen-resolution)

Comment: No...I actually have already set the screen resolution.  I'm trying to get zoom straightened out but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: So, what do you mean by everything? You are in the ISE and / or VSCode, or some other editor, and you zoom the script pane or consolehost, and you are saying, you want to zoom the whole editor / consolehost UI when you zoom the editor? Then no, that is not possible. The main app windows are all screen res stuff not work-area zooming.

Comment: yes that's the conclusion I was coming to.